# Assemble - can't reuse {{>body}}: "The partial body could not be found"

Tags: gruntjs, handlebars.js, assemble

First of all, forgive me if this is a silly question. I am new to assemble (started using it last week) and StackOverflow.

I'm trying to use the partial "body" twice on a layout, like this:

```
{{>body}}
{{>body}}
```

And I get the error message from the title: `The partial body could not be found`.

My original intention actually was to use that for selective markdown rendering, such as:

```
{{#is (extname page.src) "md"}}
    {{#markdown}}
        {{>body}}
    {{/markdown}}
{{else}}
    {{>body}}
{{/is}}
```

But in that case I get the same error when the page is not markdown.

Does this sound like a legit issue? Just trying to help, that's all. :-)

(BTW, for the selective markdown issue I just implemented a `{{#markdown-if}}` helper that does the job, so I don't need help getting that logic to work. I just want to help assemble in case this behavior I found sounds like a real issue.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting use case... We used to register the page content as a `body` partial, but stopped doing that and instead use Regex to replace the `{{>body}}` tag with the page content. I think you should [open an issue](https://github.com/assemble/assemble/issues/new) to request that we substitute all the body tags instead of just the first occurrence.

So to answer the question... Assemble does a `string.replace` and only replaces the first occurrence, so you'll get an error if trying to use `{{>body}}` twice.

Comment: thanks a ton, man. I will open an issue documenting this. Replacing all occurrences of `{{>body}}` sounds like the way to go!

Comment: Thanks for the PR on this. It's really helpful to have people in the community working on some of these things.

Comment: Thanks for all the support & awesome feedback @doowb! Right now I'm caught up in the middle of something, but I want to contribute more in the future! Cheers! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this in 0.4.12 with the initializeEngine option and changing the two {{> body }} references to just {{ body }}

See https://github.com/assemble/assemble/pull/468#issuecomment-38730532